# In VB.Net, how to repopulate a datagrid from scratch?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagrid, sqlcommand, dataadapter

I have written a generic VB.net subroutine that populates a datagrid with the results of a query.  The subroutine as one parameter, strQuery, which is a string that can translate to any valid SQL-Server view or stored procedure that returns a recordset.  Other than that, there is no constraint on the SQL code, and sending two queries that have entirely different field profiles is a valid proposition.

In order to get this to work, I must completely purge the data grid of whatever dataset had been there previously, thus allowing the control to drop its prior identity and start over, allowing, from scratch, the new dateset to redefine the control's contents.

I have finally solved the problem.  Perhaps I should have mentioned that I am using Visual Studio 2010, and that if Hersey were using a later version, then the code that worked for him may not have worked for me.  The change to my code is one additional line: setting both the name and datapropertyname to the same name. I noticed that when I went to look at the column view, I noticed that the datapropertyname is how the table links to the source, and the name is an effective alias for the field, how it will be presented.  Obviously, for clarity sake, both must be the same!  This now works as advertised.
Thanks, ~ Peter Ferber

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("<Enter Connection string here>")
    Dim rcd As ADODB.Recordset = ReturnRecordset("Select * From ExcludeWords")
    Call DefineDataGrid("Select * From ExcludeWords")
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Call DefineDataGrid("Select * From FindWords")
End Sub

Sub DefineDataGrid(ByVal strQuery As String)
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("<Enter Connection String Here>")
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    FindWordGrid.Columns.Clear()
    FindWordGrid.DataSource = Nothing

    Dim rcd As ADODB.Recordset = ReturnRecordset(strQuery)

    Dim MyField As ADODB.Field

    Dim iCount As Integer = -1
    FindWordGrid.ColumnCount = rcd.Fields.Count
    For Each MyField In rcd.Fields
        iCount = iCount + 1
        FindWordGrid.Columns(iCount).Name = MyField.Name
        FindWordGrid.Columns(iCount).DataPropertyName = MyField.Name
    Next

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    FindWordGrid.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Function ReturnRecordset(strQuery As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection = "<Enter Connection string here>"

    ReturnRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    ReturnRecordset.Open(strQuery, con)
End Function
```

My setup is easy to reproduce: I am using datasets with only a handful of records in each respective table.  The only constraint is that the respective runs must have a different field profile.  I have been experimenting with different techniques for much of the day, and I now think it best to get some new grey matter on the subject.  Getting this process correctly is the last major hurdle for me, in making a key presentation I wish to make, in lobbying for a job role.  Thanks, in advance, for your comments, thoughts, and ideas.
Sincerely, ~ Peter Ferber

Comment: Firstly, your code will not work with "any valid SQL-Server view or stored procedure". It will only work with an actual `SELECT` statement because you are accepting the default `CommandType` of `Text`.

Comment: If there are no rows after binding then there are no rows in the data source. You can check how many records were retrieved by looking at the number returned by the `Fill` method.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  In an attempt to clear the column collection, I added the following line:

Comment: If your queries may not produce result sets with the same schema then you need to clear the existing columns from the grid. To do that, set the `DataSource` to `Nothing`, `Clear` the `Columns` collection and then set the `DataSource` again. That will automatically generate new columns.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  In an attempt to clear the column collection, I changed the code block in the original question to show my updated attempt to follow jmcihinney's instruction.  When I do, either above or below the line setting th datasource to nothing, I get a blank datagrid on my first pass.  In writing "FindWordGrid.Columns.Clear()", something seems to dismantle to the data grid functionality completely.  Am I doing something wrong?  

With respect, may I suggest reproducing the simple setup I've described and testing your fixes?  Thank you.  ~ Peter Ferber

Comment: Firstly, I specifically said to set the `DataSource` to `Nothing` before clearing the columns. As for the issue, debug your code. If you can't provide us with ALL the relevant information then you're not asking a proper question.

Comment: Sorry.  Please don't take offense.  I done my level best to be as specific and methodical as possible.  And I am asking only that which I would be willing to do, and have done, myself.  If I sounded ungrateful, I did not intend it; and I apologize if that's how my communication came off.  Consider that I appreciated your feedback sufficiently that yours was the suggestion I pursued.  Mia culpa.

Comment: Given that I'm the only one who has commented, I'd certainly take offence if you pursued anyone else's suggestion. I just want people to read the advice provided when they ask for it and follow the instructions provided. That includes doing things in the order specified and also doing all the things specified. Have you looked at the result of the `Fill` method? You haven't indicated that you have. I also expect people to debug properly, e.g. watch the `Columns.Count` and `Rows.Count` properties as you step through the code that clears and repopulates the grid.

Comment: To your point, I have, yet again, provided a full set of code in the initial question, so that you have a full picture of what I'm trying to do.  FIndWords and ExcludeWords are two tables with a small handful of records.  The same routine is run twice: the first time when the form loads, and the second when I press an update button.  It's bare bones, so as to avoid any outside noise.

Comment: ...which leads me to my second question.  One possible solution: after clearing the columns, rebuild them with the fields known to be in the new table.  Looking at the watch window, I see under the dataset's columns, both "_List" and "List" as the names of fields the query produces.  However, typing "_List" nor "List", as a property of the FieldList object, produces an error.  

After clearing fields, must I then manually repopulate the data grid with the new field configuration?  And why can't I make operational use of "_LIst" or "List", precisely what I might need, in my code?  Thank you.

Comment: There is no need for you to be looking at the `DataTable` (not `DataSet`). When you bind a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView` whose `AutoGenerateColumns` property is `True`, which it is by default, the grid will automatically generate a column for each column in the `DataTable` unless a grid column already exists with its `DataPropertyName` set to the name of that table column. If there are no grid columns, there can be no such existing column. For the third time, what does `Fill` return and what is the value of the column and row counts before and after rebinding?

Comment: Sorry Peter, I'm not sure I'm going to be anymore help to you.  You've not followed the suggestion anyone has made and completely over complicated the solution.  The answer I provided (While room for improvement as Mary suggests) just plan works.  If that isn't working, you've either not implemented correctly, or there is something else outside the scope of this question at play

Answer (score 2):

So, made a couple modifications to the DefineDataGrid code you've posted.  Seems to be working for me.  I suspect might be something to do with the life cycle of either your cmd or con objects causing your problem.  Parsing a number of different number of queries through to it and it rebuilds the datagridview correctly

```
Sub DefineDataGrid(ByVal strQuery As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    FindWordGrid.DataSource = Nothing
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
            Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            FindWordGrid.DataSource = dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Changed the obvious module level implementations of con and cmd to local variables, and since both types implement IDisposable, wrapped them in a Using pattern

Comment: That's awesome, Hursey.  Thank you for the due diligence on this.  I get an error the second time I encounter the line "da.Fill(dt)", and the error I get is "The connectionstring property is not initialized".  That's OK, and it seems to me that your assessment about lifecycle is the right track.  I will keep noodling.  That you have succeeded on your end tells me that the solution is near at hand.  Thanks much!

Comment: @user3621522, the code posted explicitly says *"Your Connection String Here"* so if your `ConnectionString` property is not set then you have ignored that part.

Comment: The posted code neglects to clear the grid's columns after clearing the `DataSource`, which means that columns from previous queries will remain.

Comment: That's awesome, Hursey.  Thank you for the due diligence on this.  I was getting the error the second time I encounter the line "da.Fill(dt)", saying "The connectionstring property is not initialized".  So, I changed created a new connection within the subroutine, and that keeps the error from happening, but the old field configuration is still in force during the second run.  I feel confident I am on the right track, as you have a proven success rate using this method.  Good work, and thanks!

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yeah, thought exactly that myself, but in my tests here worked perfectly without clearing the columns.  I think going by the OP latest comment though, there is something else going on  with his connection management that is screwing things up

Comment: Did you use the same query each time in those tests or maybe multiple queries with the same schema? I'm not sure how existing columns could be removed from the grid without code to explicitly do so.

Comment: @user3621522, Maybe update your question with your latest attempt and include how you creating your connection

Comment: @jmcilhinney Different schema in each test.  Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Actually, I just tested and the "old" columns are automatically removed. I thought maybe that it was because there was no `BindingSource` but I tested that and saw the same result. I would swear that, when I tested previously, no columns were removed. That was some time ago though, so either something has changed in the `DataGridView` or there was something wrong with my previous tests or I was just plain mistaken.

Comment: @user3621522 What do you mean by "So, I changed created a new connection within the subroutine"?

Comment: @Hursey This is nitpicking on my part but I would not assign the `DataSource` until after the last `End Using` I just hate to hold a connection open while the user interface is being updated. Hope you don't mind an observation.

Comment: I updated the code with the state of the art, and I also updated the last paragraph to show what new method I'd tried and where they failed.  I do think that I have the task of programmatically of clearing the field names and then repopulating the table.  If that's the case, I'll take anything that actually works.  I have no idea why my attempt to open a recordset failed.  Ghosts in the machine, perhaps? :-) ~ Peter Ferber

Comment: I made an additional update, fixing the problem with getting an accurate field list; and, for some reason, the table twice populates with the right number of rows and the right field names, only the field values are all blank.  Any thoughts on why that might be?  Anyway, I'm still happy to report that the ghosts have vacated the machinery.  ~ Peter Ferber

Comment: My code finally works.  I have added one final paragraph designating the finished work.  As one using VB.Net 2010, it may be that more recent versions of the program solve the problem using Hursey's code, but it didn't work for me.  I was definitely helped along the way, and I appreciate all the suggestions that came my way that proved actionable.  ~ Peter Ferber